# Receiving correct data in JSON format but unable to bind it to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have `$.ajax` which fetches data in JSON format. but I am unable to bind it to my table using jquery's datatable. The js code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Result.aspx/getUsers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
        var dataParsed = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        console.log(dataParsed);
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "aadData": data.d,
            "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "username" },
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "last_name" },
        { "data": "phone_no" },
        { "data": "address" },
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "user_type" },
        ]
        });
      }
    });
 });
```

No error is shown in the console but neither is the data bound to my table.
The html code is as below:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>UserId</td>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td>PhoneNumber</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>EmailId</td>
        <td>UserType</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

please suggest me any solution and reason why this is happening

Comment: What response you are getting?

Comment: I am getting response by converting datatable to json string using javascript serializer. The data.d is [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]. Say for example

Comment: try `console.log()` your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing json data and assigning in a variable but not using it in Datatable so use,

```
"aaData": dataParsed, // its aaData not aadData
```

Instead of

```
"aadData": data.d,
```

You have another typo(may be) it is **aaData** but you are using **aadData**. Also you need to parse your JSON and need to make an array of data like,

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "$320,800"],
  ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "$170,750"],
  ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "$86,000"],
  ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "$162,700"],
  ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "$372,000"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
        title: "Name"
      },
      {
        title: "Position"
      },
      {
        title: "Office"
      },
      {
        title: "Salary"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: used dataParsed instead of data.d but still same result. The table shows No data available in table.